# Obtener datos aleatoriamente de la base de datos con CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, random

Resulta que necesito obtener datos random de la base de datos con el framework de `CodeIgniter`.

en la `database` tengo una tabla que se llama frases y dentro de ella dos campos:

*Tipo y* *frase*

En el campo *tipo* tengo *1* la cual tiene 5 frases y lo mismo  con *tipo 2* *tipo 3* *tipo 4* *tipo 5*

entonces quiero hacer un *select frases ramdon where tipo = 1*

y que me muestre frases aleatorias del tipo 1. buscando encontré este código:

```
function Getramdon(){

    $this->db->order_by('tipo','RANDOM');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get('frases');
    return $query->result_array();
  }
```

pero me muestra frases aletorias de otros tipos y no solo del 1 como yo le  pedi.

Comment: Con el `limit` estás diciéndole al `query` que traiga solo un registro, prueba comentándolo, o cambiándolo por algo como `$this->db->limit('0,10')`

Comment: pero, igual esta bien que me traiga 1 frase el tema es que quiero que sea aletoria, dependiendo de lo que ingrese ya sea 1,2,3,4 o 5

Answer (score 3):

Fíjate que estás pasando como argumento el string `RAMDOM` y no `RANDOM`, que sería lo correcto. Cámbialo así:

```
$this->db->order_by('tipo','RANDOM');
```

Para obtener sólo las de tipo 1 te falta la cláusula `WHERE`. Prueba añadiendo esta instrucción:

```
$this->db->where('tipo', 1);
```

Comment: gracias, ahora funciona pero me lanza aletoriamente del tipo 2 independiente que yo le ingrese 1 como valor

Comment: gracias, ya lo solucione! agregue un where $this->db->where("tipo",$tipo); entonces ahora funciona, vale.

Comment: Si la respuesta de @santiaguito te ayudó a solucionar tu problema principal te animo a que la marques como respuesta correcta!